# Perl, global match and append something after the matched string

Tags: regex, perl, match, substitution

I have a problem in the case of performing a global match.  How can I substitute the matched string for a new string, which is made up from the original string plus a new string.  The string is like:

```
$string = "t123:apple;t456:pear;t789:banana";
```

Then I have a hash like this:

```
my %hash = (
    t123 => 'fruit1',
    t456 => 'fruit2',
    t789 => 'fruit3',
);
```

How can I then obtain a new string such as:

```
$newstring = "t123 fruit1:apple;t456 fruit2:pear;t789 fruit3:banana";
```

Now, my perl code is:

```
while($string =~ /t\d{3}/g){
    if (exists $hash{"$&"}) {
        my $match = $&;
        $string =~ s/$&/$match.$hash{"$&"}/;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work though, because the match always starts from the first character. I think I should use `pos(string)` or something to make it have an offset, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is rather easy:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $string = "t123:apple;t456:pear;t789:banana";

my %hash = (
    t123 => 'fruit1',
    t456 => 'fruit2',
    t789 => 'fruit3',
);

$string =~ s/(t\d+)/$1 $hash{$1}/g;

say $string;
```

But this doesn't ensure that everything that matches `t\d{3}` is a valid key in your hash. So let's explicitly search for those keys.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $string = "t123:apple;t456:pear;t789:banana";

my %hash = (
    t123 => 'fruit1',
    t456 => 'fruit2',
    t789 => 'fruit3',
);

my $match = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %hash;

$string =~ s/($match)/$1 $hash{$1}/g;

say $string;
```